# Convert varchar2 column to number in Oracle

Tags: oracle, type-conversion

I have a table `emp_details`.

The column `emp_salary` is of type `varchar2` in which certain rows are null:

```
emp_salary
100,34
null
20,2
30,3
null
```

I need a result in which the column type is number:

```
emp_salary
100.34
null
20.2
30.3
null
```

My attempt in code is:

```
select emp_salary 
from emp_details
where emp_salary = to_number(emp_salary ,'9999D99','nls_numeric_characters=,.');
```

Error:

> ORA-01722: invalid number
>   01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
>   *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
>   *Action:   Specify a valid number.

How can I fix it?

I don't mean to compare the values. I just want to change the `varchar` to `number`. I will use it in a small part of my bigger function, using [`TO_NUMBER`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions191.htm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sort of almost there. You sound like you're doing a conversion of a selected value rather than a filter and you need to cater for NULLs so:-

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(NVL(emp_salary,'0'),'9999D99','nls_numeric_characters=,.')
FROM emp_details
```