# UseWho gives me an example of the total salary format comma

Tags: oracle

Who gives me an example of the total salary this

```
 Select sum(to_char(salary,'9,999,999')) from employees;
```

Output
Ora-01722

Comment: Welcome to the DBA StackExchange. Is this an Oracle Question or a MySQL Question ???

Comment: Oracle Sorry, it was a mistake

Comment: I selected sql but it was rejected why

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert varchar2 column to number in Oracle](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/132967/convert-varchar2-column-to-number-in-oracle)

Comment: Sorry, no
I want the total to be in this format

Comment: '9,999,999' this format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting to character *before* you complete the sum, which must be done to a number. Reverse the order of your functions - do all the math before you change the data type to char:

```
select to_char(sum(salary),'9,999,999') from employees;
```